# im new to react-native i want to stytle but im getting error

Tags: react-native

i want to style a component in react-native but I'm getting error I have tried all i can but I need more explanation on how to go about this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style={},
  textStyle={},
  size=125,
  ...props
})=>{
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{...props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const styles = (size)=> StyleSheet.create({
  radius:{
    borderRadius:size/2,
    width:size,
    height:size
  },
  text:{
    color:'#fff',
    fontSize: 20
  }

})
```

this is the error im getting when i use a styled in react-native but i'm still getting the same issue

```
src/components/RoundedButton.js (18:3)
Unused style detected: undefined.radius (react-native/no-unused-styles)
(ESLint)
src/components/RoundedButton.js (23:3)
Unused style detected: undefined.text (react-native/no-unused-styles)
(ESLint)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, first you have an error:

> error **Spread children are not supported in React**

Don't do this:

```js
    <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{...props.title}</Text>
```

But:

```js
    <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
```

...and I think you should use styles otherwise:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radius: (size) => ({
    borderRadius:size/2,
    width:size,
    height:size,
  }),
  text:{
    color:'black',
    fontSize: 20
  }
```

This is all the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style={},
  textStyle={},
  size=125,
  ...props
})=>{
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radius: (size) => ({
    borderRadius:size/2,
    width:size,
    height:size,
  }),
  text:{
    color:'black',
    fontSize: 20
  }

})
```

Comment: You're welcome, if the issue is fixed, don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted :)